I cannot post a question

I have a question about my Cryptography Stack Exchange post: Can BGV scheme work with congruent values
I have an account on 'math' and I tried to ask a question on 'crypto'. I created a new account and asked my question. Then I realized that I can use my original account from 'math'. I immediately deleted the question and deleted the new profile (which I just created). Now I tried to ask the same question again but getting a response "This post appears to be a duplicate of". I waited for 3 days and rephrased the question. But still I am getting this stupid duplicate response.
What should I do in this case? How can I ask a question which has never been asked before, but the system thinks it has?

I can try and destroy your other account, that will permanently delete any questions you've posted. Let me know if this is what you are after. I'm checking to be sure that this will let you post the identical question.

Nope, that's apparently not working. You can contact the mod team to let them merge the account. I'd make very clear which account you want to keep, as the names are identical, so reference them by number! Explain that you want to keep the account that posted here. Contact CM is on the left bottom of each page.

When I tried merging, I got an error message "oops, profile does not exist". I have sent just a general question with a link to this post. Hopefully it will be resolved.

Wait, this question on meta and the question on crypto seems to be asked under this same account. Are you sure that this hasn't been resolved already? I'll try if I can undelete.

Yeah, I can undelete just fine, and so should you. I've deleted it again as it is not my place to undelete.

No, the user which I wanted to merge (and remove) is 108425 which is different to 108426. Now the post shows that it is deleted by you. I do not have access to the account 108425.
And have exactly the same error "This post appears to be a duplicate" when I try to post again.
Why is it not possible to delete the post completely so it never appears as a duplicate?

I'll undelete the post as it has been posted by user xxx26, i.e. you, and I'm pretty sure that I can undelete it without it being a problem. I do think that the problem was resolved: "User: oddy (108425) (Account.Id=28062992) deleted by oddy (108426) merging with 108426" Let me know if anything else is amiss. You've probably been able to undelete the question for 2 days :)

Thank you. It is on. I do not have to do anything now. Right?

Nope, I'll remove my final comment below the Q.
